# c programming input last element is @

Tags: c, arrays, input

I am studying c language from book by Brian W. Kernighan (Author), Dennis M. Ritchie (Author) on exercise 2-5:

> Write the function any(s1,s2), which returns the first location in a string s1
>   where any character from the string s2 occurs, or -1 if s1 contains no characters from s2.
>   (The standard library function strpbrk does the same job but returns a pointer to the
>   location.)

i have this issue last element of input is '@' this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void chloc(char s1[], char s2[]);

main(void)
{
    int c, i, j;
    char s1[20], s2[20];
    i = j = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
        s1[i++] = c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
        s2[j++] = c;

    chloc(s1, s2);

    return 0;

}

void chloc(char s1[], char s2[]){

    int i, j, b, k;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for( i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
        for(j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; j++)
            if(s1[i] == s2[j]){
                printf("First uccurance of %d is %d\n", s1[i], i);
                s2[j] = '#';
            }


}
```

Comment: What is your issue? What do you want and what does this code give you?

Comment: on this input 'beqabeqa' , be

Comment: `char s1[20], s2[20];` --> `char s1[20] = {0}, s2[20] ={0};`

Comment: "on this input 'beqabeqa' , be" ???

Comment: No idea what you're talking about. Try to use whole sentences.

Comment: Whatever your chloc is doing, its not what it should be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input code doesn't `'\0'`-terminate your char arrays, so they're not valid strings (all strings are terminated by `'\0'`). That's why your string processing function accesses elements past the end, reading garbage.

You can fix it like this:

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    s1[i++] = c;
s1[i] = '\0';
while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    s2[j++] = c;
s2[j] = '\0';
```

but you should really make sure you also don't read more characters than the arrays can store (19 chars + 1 terminator).

Also, the function is supposed to *return* the result, not print it (according to the exercise).